# How to provide mock files to change event of <input type='file'> for unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having difficulties with a unit test in which I want to verify the processing of a file, which would usually be selected in the view via `<input type='file'>`.

In the controller part of my AngularJS app the file is processed inside the input's change event like so:

```
//bind the change event of the file input and process the selected file
inputElement.on("change", function (evt) {
    var fileList = evt.target.files;
    var selectedFile = fileList[0];
    if (selectedFile.size > 500000) {
        alert('File too big!');
    // ...
```

I'd like `evt.target.files` to contain my mock data instead of the user's selected file in my unit test. I realized that I can't instantiate a `FileList` and `File` object by myself, which would be the according objects the browser is working with. So I went with assigning a mock FileList to the input's `files` property and triggering the change event manually:

```
describe('document upload:', function () {
    var input;

    beforeEach(function () {
        input = angular.element("<input type='file' id='file' accept='image/*'>");
        spyOn(document, 'getElementById').andReturn(input);
        createController();
    });

    it('should check file size of the selected file', function () {
        var file = {
            name: "test.png",
            size: 500001,
            type: "image/png"
        };

        var fileList = {
            0: file,
            length: 1,
            item: function (index) { return file; }
        };

        input.files = fileList; // assign the mock files to the input element 
        input.triggerHandler("change"); // trigger the change event

        expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('File too big!');
    });
```

Unfortunately, this causes the following error in the controller which shows that this attempt failed because the files were not assigned to the input element at all:

> **TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'evt.target.files')**

I already found out that the `input.files` property is **read-only** for security reasons. So I started another approach by dispatching a customized change which would provide the files property, but still without success.

**So long story short: I'd be eager to learn a working solution or any best practices on how to approach this test case.**

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just a jqLite?

Comment: tacking a few props onto new Blobs() should leave you with something that quacks an awful lot like a File()...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's rethink AngularJS,  `DOM must be handled in a directive`

We should not deal with DOM element in a controller, i.e. `element.on('change', ..`, especially for testing purpose.  In a controller, You talk to data, not to DOM.

Thus, those `onchange` should be a directive like the following

```
<input type="file" name='file' ng-change="fileChanged()" /> <br/>
```

However, unfortunately, `ng-change` does not work well with `type="file"`. I am not sure that the future version works with this or not.  We still can apply the same method though.

```
<input type="file" 
  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged(this.files)" />
```

and in the controller, we just simply define a method

```
$scope.fileChanged = function(files) {
  return files.0.length < 500000;
};
```

Now, everything is just a normal controller test. No more dealing with `angular.element`, `$compile`, `triggers`, etc.! :)

```
describe(‘MyCtrl’, function() {
  it('does check files', inject(
    function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.new();
      ctrl = $controller(‘UploadCtrl’, {‘$scope’: scope});

      var files = { 0: {name:'foo', size: 500001} };
      expect(scope.fileChanged(files)).toBe(true);
    }
  ));
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1J7ETus0etBLO18FQDhK?p=preview

Comment: Note I think the scope() is a debug-only function, not really appropriate for production code.

Comment: A bit confused with this answer as it starts by saying "must be handled in a directive" and then gives an example without using a directive.   If you place in a directive (which is good advice!) you are right back to needing the trigger / $compile and finding a way to pass the files object to your handler.  The answer by @runTarm explains how to do the latter.

Comment: @user1821052, it starts by saying "DOM must be handled...", and goes on to state "We should not deal with DOM element in a controller", indicating the solution does not manipulate the DOM inside a controller.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @PeteBD,

Since angularjs version 1.2.22, the jqLite are now support passing a custom event object to `triggerHandler()`. See: [d262378b](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d262378b7c047dcd925cf4b55b80c0697b292232)

---

**If you are using only jqLite**,

the `triggerHandler()` will never work as it will pass a dummy event object to handlers.

The dummy event object look like this (copied from [jqLite.js#L962](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/jqLite.js#L962))

```
{
  preventDefault: noop,
  stopPropagation: noop
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't even have a `target` property.

**If you are using jQuery**,

you could trigger an event with a custom event object like this:

```
input.triggerHandler({
  type: 'change',
  target: {
    files: fileList
  }
});
```

and the `evt.target.files` will be the `fileList` as you are expecting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your sophisticated answer! I'd aspire a working solution with jqLite (or even without jqLite at all) rather than with jQuery, because I don't necessarily want to switch to jQuery just for this issue. If no other viable solution is proposed, I will come back to your answer and accept it. Thank you again!

Comment: @runTarm is correct here.  jqLite should be fixed in this regard by https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8505

Comment: I don't personally see a problem with utilizing jQuery for test-only...that way you can keep your deployed product lean and still get the functionality that the jQuery can provide for a test.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example spec for input file/image using angular2+.

```
it('should call showError on toastService Api on call of onSaveOfImage() method', () => {

    spyOn(component.commonFacade.fileIOApi, 'uploadFile');
    let file = new File([new ArrayBuffer(2e+5)], 'test-file.jpg', { lastModified: null, type: 'image/jpeg' });
    let fileInput={ files: [file] };
    component['onSaveOfImage'](fileInput,"",null,"","");
    expect(component.commonFacade.fileIOApi.uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.uploadedFileData).toBeUndefined();
    expect(component.commonFacade.employeeApi.toastService.showError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Adrita Sharma in another post, an easy way to mock a valid value to the `event.target.files` is using **DataTransfer** objects. With it, you can create a FileList object.

This following sample works in jasmine 4.5:

```
it('should simulate file selection', () => {
        const file = new File(['file contents'], 'file.txt', { type: 'text/plain' });

        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.items.add(file);

        const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input');

        // That's the trick
        inputElement.files = dataTransfer.files;

        // now event.target.files must have a file

        inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        
        {...}

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your file change handler should probably be a function directly on your controller. You can bind that function to the change event either from the HTML or a directive. That way you can call your handler function directly without worrying about triggering an event. This egghead.io video covers a couple ways you can do that: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads

There are a lot of things you need to worry about when rolling your own file uploader with Angular so I would just use one of the existing libraries out there that takes care of it. e.g. [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Comment: I'm well aware of these directives, but they don't solve the problem since I'm only concerned with this fundamental mechanic of the file input (which any directive would also rely on) and how to properly unit test it using mock data. Binding the change event in the view and using a callback function on the controller which can be called directly (instead of triggering the change event) within the unit test would work, but generally I'd like to be able to solve this even when the change event is bound via JavaScript like described in my code. So for me the question still remains.