# Jasmine test for input type file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write the unit test for file upload but I am not able to satisfy below condition to bypass the validation. Can someone help me to complete the test.

```
if($scope.selected.files == undefined || $scope.selected.files == null || $scope.selected.files.length == 0){
    $window.alert("Please select upload file.");
    return;
}
```

I want to satisfy the above condition so it should not display alert message.

I tried below test but it is not passing the length validation.

```
it("should validate the selected file size.",
    function() {
       debugger
        $scope.fileSelection = true;

       var file= {
            "lastModified": 1438583972000,
            "lastModifiedDate": "2015-08-03T06:39:32.000Z",
            "name": "gitignore_global.txt",
            "size": 236,
            "type": "text/plain",
            "data": "data:text/plain;base64,DQojaWdub3JlIHRodW1ibmFpbHMgY3JlYXRlZCBieSB3aW5kb3dz…xoDQoqLmJhaw0KKi5jYWNoZQ0KKi5pbGsNCioubG9nDQoqLmRsbA0KKi5saWINCiouc2JyDQo="
        }
        var files = [];
        files[0] = { file,fileType:{id:'1'}};
        $scope.selected = {files};

        spyOn(window, 'alert');
        createController();
        $scope.transferFile();
        expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith("The selected upload file is empty. Please upload the valid file.");

    });
```

Comment: Isn't your testcase failing because of mismatch in String parameter? i.e. `"Please select upload file."` in your code vs `"The selected upload file is empty. Please upload the valid file."` in your expect

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I was doing some other mistake below is the corrected code.

Comment: var files = [{ file,fileType:{id:'1'}}];
            spyOn(window, 'alert');
            createController();            
            $scope.selected = {
              files : [file],
              fileType: {id:'1'}
            };

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097738/how-to-provide-mock-files-to-change-event-of-input-type-file-for-unit-testin  look this example