# Unit Testing Custom File Input Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am having a huge problem with getting a unit test to work for a custom file directive for angular 1.5.0 and Jasmine 2.4, I have looked at

[How to provide mock files to change event of <input type='file'> for unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097738/how-to-provide-mock-files-to-change-event-of-input-type-file-for-unit-testin)

However this only seems to work for a raw input file field and not a custom directive.

First the directive, pretty straight forward model assignment.  I also trigger a outside function on the scope which I make sure is in the unit test and don't get any errors from that.  I just for the life of me can't force a change event to happen on the file input.

```
app.directive('fileModel', fileModel);
fileModel.$inject = ['$parse', '$log'];

function fileModel ($parse, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files);
                    scope.parseFolder(scope.myFolder);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Here is the unit test, right now I am trying to trigger and event via a button because I couldn't get a manual event trigger to happen but that isn't working either.

```
describe('fileModel', function () {

    var $compile, $rootScope, directiveElem;

    beforeEach(module("LocalModule"));

    beforeEach(function(){

        inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        });

        directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
    });

    function getCompiledElement(){
        var element = angular.element('<div ng-controller="UploadCtrl as upload"><input id ="upload" type="file" file-model="myFolder"/><button type="button" id="button" ng-click="clickUpload()">Upload</button></div>');
        var compiledElement = $compile(element)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.clickUpload = function(){
            angular.element('#upload').trigger('click');
        };
        $rootScope.$digest();
        return compiledElement;
    }

    it('should have input element', function () {
        var inputElement = directiveElem.find('input');
        expect(inputElement).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('watched the change function', function () {
        var file = {
            name: "test.png",
            size: 500001,
            type: "image/png"
        };

        var fileList = {
            0: file,
            length: 1,
            item: function (index) { return file; }
        };
        var inputElement = directiveElem.find('input');
        var buttonElement = directiveElem.find('#button');
        inputElement.files = fileList;
        directiveElem.triggerHandler({
            type: 'change',
            target: {
                files: fileList
            }
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
        buttonElement.triggerHandler('click');
    }); 


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and ran across this. I was able to get this to work by calling `$rootScope.$apply();` after the `triggerHandler` method instead of `$rootScope.$digest();`.